# What is an exploded EAR?

Tags: ear

Can someone please explain what's an `exploded EAR` ? I checked in google but couldn't find a clear answer.
Is it a different format?

What's the difference to a non `exploded EAR`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/deployment/overview.html#1036349 does this help? from what it reads it just means an extracted EAR file...

Answer (score 3):

A compressed EAR file, with extension **.ear** is just a [ZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) file containing the directory structure of a JEE project. It is normally used in order to deploy a JEE project.

An exploded EAR file is just the uncompressed content of the above.

Incidentally speaking, **war** and **jar** files are also compressed in ZIP format.

The use of the wording "*Exploding*" instead of "*decompressing*" a ZIP file seems to be traditional in the java community, and is present in official documentation.

E.g.: www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/classforexplodingjarzipfilesontothefilesystem.htm (on a IBM contributed source file belonging to Eclipse ).

They can be exploded with the **jar** command.

You can also use any compression utility, provided you keep the directory structure intact.

e.g.:

```
jar xvd /myapp_path/myapp.ear
```

Comment: Guiseppe Fadda   Why use exploded word here? why don't use `uncompressed`?

Comment: Probably tradition, history I would personally use the word "uncompressed".
As you can notice in the link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/deployment/overview.html#1036349 which Natzyrhc pointed out, Oracle documentation uses the word "Exploded" as a synonim for "uncompressed". Probably someone at Oracle or Sun found the idea of "exploding packages" an amusing joke on words.